# Почему код срабатывает только после обновления страницы?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: у меня на сайте вход в личный кабинет происходит асинхронно, и вот этот код не отрабатывает асинхронно, срабатывает только после обновления страницы:

```
$(".authform").hide().fadeIn(500).html(res + '<div class="aq"><img class="smail" src="views/ir/images/smail.png" /><br /><a class="new_ordersss" href="?view=new_orders">Мои заказы(<?php $count_orders?>)</a></div>\r\n <a class="vixodPolzovatel" href="?do=logout">Выйти</a>');
```

А именно не срабатывает только:

```
<?php $count_orders?>
```

Повторюсь: после обновления страницы все хорошо.

Comment: 1. Без echo вообще ничего никогда выводиться не будет.
2. Вы же понимаете, где выполняется php, а где js?

Comment: @Etki, Мои заказы(<?php echo $count_orders ?>), так не работает, если не правильно исправте пожалуйста

Comment: @Alextrue, где выполняется php и где javascript? Это критично для понимания, почему ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Передаём из шаблона переменную `$count_orders`.

```
<orders data-count="<?php echo $count_orders; ?>"> </orders>
```

и принимаем её вот в таком виде

```
Мои заказы(' + $('orders').data('count') + ')
```

P.S. Вроде, правильно всё описал. xD